# Need to incorporate a UISlider in cocos2d

Tags: xcode4, cocos2d-iphone, slider

I've noticed that cocos2d doesn't story board like in Xcode 4. I wanted to add a slider form which you control the player's movement/movement speed across the iPhone screen. How can i add slider and hook it up to the sprite movement/movement speed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You use the CCUIViewWrapper custom class.

Here is the link for it: [CCUIViewWrapper github](https://github.com/splhack/CCUIViewWrapper)

And here is a tutorial how to use it: [Tutorial Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=boN-5WZBhtk)

Comment: Ok i did exactly what the video said to do but i got a bunch of errors concerning the wrapper for the slider. If you could help me with the error that would be great.

Comment: its probably just some deprecated methods, search on what should be replaced instead.

Comment: The exact error messages i get are as follows:Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CCUIViewWrapper", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in HelloWorldLayer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I just tried and it worked perfectly for me. I dont know what you have done to get that error.

Comment: What you should do is the folowing: 
1. Drag in the folder containing CCUIViewWrapper .h and .m
2. #import the uikit and CCUIViewWrapper in your scene.
3. Create the UISlider.
4. CCUIViewWrapper *wrapper = [CCUIViewWrapper wrapperForUIView:slider];
5. [self addChild:wrapper];

Comment: Ok im getting the same exact error codes regarding the "CCUIViewWrapper."

Comment: You usually get that error when you forget a framework. Make sure the UIKit is imported and added to the project and the CCUIViewWrapper is imported where you want to use it

Comment: I tried to remove the reference of UIKit framework and I got the error you got. So as I understand it you havent added the UIKit framework to your project.